# How to solve org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException when copying data from one database to another?

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to copy data from one database to another. All is working fine, until one of the rows in the source database is modified (stack trace below) . Adding new rows to destination database works as expected.

I have a context file for each database connection (mysql and hsqldb) consisting of the following beans:

```
    <bean id="mysqlDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${mysql.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${mysql.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${mysql.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${mysql.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="mysqlTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="mysqlEntityManagerFactory" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="mysqlDataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="mysqlEntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource"          ref="mysqlDataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter"    ref="mysqlVendorAdaptor" />
        <property name="packagesToScan"      value="my.packages.to.scan"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mysqlEntityManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="mysqlEntityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mysqlVendorAdaptor" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" >
        <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="${mysql.dialect}" />
    </bean>
```

In my `@Service` I create a `JpaRepository` for each database connection:

```
@Autowired
private EntityManager hsqldbEntityManager;

@Autowired
private EntityManager mysqlEntityManager;

private MyRepository hsqldbDao;
private MyRepository mysqlDao;

public void init() {
    hsqldbDao = new JpaRepositoryFactory(hsqldbEntityManager).getRepository(MyRepository.class);
    mysqlDao = new JpaRepositoryFactory(mysqlEntityManager).getRepository(MyRepository.class);
}
```

`MyRepository` is very simple:

```
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyClass, byte[]>{ }
```

I am wiring 2 service methods together using Spring Integration. The service methods are as follows:

```
@Transactional("mysqlTransactionManager")
public List<MyClass> findAll() {
    List<MyClass> list= mysqlDao.findAll();
    return list;
}

@Transactional("hsqldbTransactionManager")
public void persist(List<MyClass> list) {
    hsqldbDao.save(list);
    hsqldbDao.flush();
}
```

I have tried detaching the list from both `EntityManager`s and deep cloning the list before the save, with the same error. Therefore I think it has something to do with the way I have configured the transactions/entitymanagers.

Any help appreciated.

Stack Trace:

```
[task-scheduler-1] ERROR org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler - org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:76)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(MethodInvokingMessageHandler.java:59)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:102)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:157)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:128)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:288)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:149)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.handleMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractTransactionSynchronizingPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractTransactionSynchronizingPollingEndpoint.java:82)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:146)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:144)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:236)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:48)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:49)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:231)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:53)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.wrapStaleStateException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1241)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1167)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1148)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1154)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:695)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
    at $Proxy21.merge(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:353)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:384)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:333)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:318)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor$LockModePopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy22.save(Unknown Source)
    at my.package.MyService.persist(xxxxx)
    at my.package.MyService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$c484c23b.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:689)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
    at my.package.MyService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$ed6874cf.persist(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:69)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:84)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:57)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:102)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:102)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:126)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:227)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.process(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:73)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [model.MyClass#[B@d76d1e]
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:485)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:255)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:867)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:851)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:855)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:686)
    ... 71 more
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have optimistic locking configured on your entities, using an `@Version` annotated field. The principle of optimistic locking is to only allow an update of a row if the version stored in the row has the same value as the one stored in the entity being merged. Otherwise, the exception you get is thrown.

So, if you want to bypass this check, you'll have to get the version from the entity to update, copy it to the detached entity being merged (as if you loaded this entity from the target database), and then merge the entity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, will have to wait till Tuesday to try this when I get back to work. I did see this somewhere else and checked my model and did not find `@Version` IIRC. I used Hibernate tools to reverse engineer the java classes from database, so may have missed something... Thanks again

Comment: Thank you, this was the problem. The field annotated `@Version` was not actually a version, reverse engineering process added the annotation. Removed the annotation and no problems...

Comment: However, bypassing the check is a bad idea because it can lead to lost updates.

Answer (score 2):

I was stuck in similar situation and my steps that helped me were:

1. Commented out the @version annotation from my entity's column
2. And created column update and create to keep the track of last updated time.

Code:

```
public class AuditEntity implements Serializable {

    private Date created;

    //    @Version
    private Date updated;

    public Date getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(Date created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    public Date getUpdated() {
        return updated;
    }

    public void setUpdated(Date updated) {
        this.updated = updated;
    }

    @PrePersist
    private void onCreate() {
        setCreated(Date.now());
        setUpdated(Date.now());
    }

    @PostUpdate
    private void onUpdate() {
        setUpdated(Date.now());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that the correct annotation on the onUpdate() method is @PreUpdate.