# Hibernate and MSSQL 2016 issue

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jdbc, sql-server-2016

I'm facing a problem with a Java application (JVM 1.6) that is using Hibernate 3.6 to access a Microsoft SQL Server via Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server.

When working with SQL JDBC  driver 3.0 and MSSQL 2008 - 2014 all is working just fine.

But when I'm trying to use MSSQL 2016, the latest "Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.0" (sqljdbc4.jar) - I get a bunch of those errors:

```
org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)
```

It happens on different entities, and can happen on a get or update operations.

My question: is this an issue with Hibernate that also needs to be updated to a newer version?
I wasn't able to find any information about compatibility issues when accessing MSSQL 2016 via Java/Hibernate.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158491/staleobjectstateexception-row-was-updated-or-deleted-by or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645694/row-was-updated-or-deleted-by-another-transaction-or-unsaved-value-mapping-was might be relevant

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732156/how-to-solve-org-hibernate-staleobjectstateexception-when-copying-data-from-one) also seems relevant.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I've seen these posts before asking here, and unfortunately they did not provide a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If possible can you try to use JVM 1.7 and sqljdbc41.jar? Better if you able to use JVM 1.8 and sqljdbc42.jar.

Microsoft recently Open Source their driver on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc). You can raise issue on their github project.

As per my understanding for SQL Server 2016 you need either sqljdbc41.jar or sqljdbc42.jar

Further you can found more official documentation on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378422(v=sql.110).aspx).

> **Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.0 and 4.2 for SQL Server:**
>   To support backward compatibility and possible upgrade scenarios, the JDBC Drivers 6.0 and 4.2 include four JAR class libraries in each installation package: sqljdbc.jar, sqljdbc4.jar, sqljdbc41.jar, and sqljdbc42.jar. Note: sqljdbc.jar, sqljdbc4.jar are provided only for backwards compatibility, and do not contain new features included with driver versions 6.0, 4.2, and 4.1.

Comment: I believe you are correct. We have recently added JVM 1.8 support to the application, so the next step would be to try it out. Thanks!